# Partitioning the edges of $K_n$ into $\lfloor \frac n6 \rfloor$ planar subgraphs

Tags: graph-theory, integer-partitions, planar-graphs

Why is it impossible to partition the edges in $K_n$ into $\lfloor \frac n6 \rfloor$ planar subgraphs for $n \ge 6$?
I'm just stuck at the beginning and can't figure out how to go about this problem.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Show that at least one of the $\lfloor \frac{n}{6}\rfloor$ subgraphs must contain more than $3n - 6$ edges.